# Concatenate contents of array object in jade to get a string

Tags: node.js, concatenation, pug

I have an object from which I extract values like so if I want a list:

```
each gear_tag in store.GearTags
 li #{gear_tag.Tag.tag_name}
```

Now I want to concatenate all **tag_name**s with **', '** in between. I mean that I want the resulting string to be something like:
"`tag_name_1, tag_name_2, tag_name_3, tag_name_4`" if the object has 4 gear_tags.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the array `.map` method combined with the `.join` method.

```
var tagString = store.GearTags.map(function (gear_tag) {
  return gear_tag.Tag.tag_name;
}).join(', ');
```

Given:

```
store.GearTags = [ 
  {Tag: {tag_name: 'tag_name_1'}}, 
  {Tag: {tag_name: 'tag_name_2'}}, 
  {Tag: {tag_name: 'tag_name_3'}}
];
```

The above logic would yield:

```
"tag_name_1, tag_name_2, tag_name_3"
```

---

[Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) iterates over every item in an array and lets you return a new value for that position in a new array that `.map` returns. Then [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) does exactly what you want, returning a concatenated string of all items in the array.

With `.map` we create a new array with only the tag name strings in it. Then with `.join` we join them all together into one big comma-separated string.

Answer (score 1):

Sad that I did not figure this out earlier.

`- var desc_tags = ''
    each gear_tag, i in store.GearTags
        - if(i == retailer.GearTags.length - 1)
            - desc_tags = desc_tags + gear_tag.Tag.tag_name
        - else
            - desc_tags = desc_tags + gear_tag.Tag.tag_name + ", "`

I was typing a "- " before the "each" statement, which was causing the code not to work.

Answer (score 0):

What if you do:

`- var desc_tags = tags.map(function(e) {return e.Tag.tag_name}).join(', ');`

Comment: Just saw Alex's solution. His goes into more detail.